# ARR V2.0 Memory Cache - Html and Image cached objects never hit

Tags: caching, iis-7, arr

i am trying on a caching solution through ARR V2 on my local machine. I have a single node server farm pointing to the oringal server. And all requests coming in to my local machine will be filtered through an inbound rule to be directed to that server farm.

In the ARR Cache action panel I have added a Cache Control Rules to always cache all objects for 20 mins for all requests directed to the server farm. Here I suppose I have overwritten the Memory cache duration settings in the server farm's caching action panel. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Some other setting on IIS includes:

1. Output caching is disabled for both user mode and kernel mode (a bit weired to me that objects are still cached in kernel cache)
2. Server proxy setting is disabled in ARR Cache action panel (I suppose this won't affect because server farm is also proxy)

After complete all the settings, I can see that All objects are cached in my disk cache when I triggered a web request. And through "netsh http show cache" I can also observe that they are all cached in kernal cache( ARR memory cache).

However, when I trigger the web request again, although the request is not going to the original server, request to html and images don't hit the memory cache and through "netsh http show cache" I can see that their hit count remain '1' and their TTL refreshed to be in sync with their corresponding disk cached objects. In contrast, css and javascript always hit memory cache till they expire. In my MIME list, they are all treated as static files so I don't understand why they behaves differently here.

Then I cleared disk cached objects (both primary and secondary), and trigger the web request again. Now (note that all objects are still in the memory cache), only html and images are cached in the disk cache while request to css and javascript are still served from the memory cache so they don'y appear in disk cache.

I just start experimenting on ARR don't fully understand the concept. Hope someone could help.

Thanks in advance.